# Looking for a single word for 'blind worship'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for 'blind worship' as in worshiping an actor blindly notwithstanding the bad performance?

Comment: For most purposes, just *worship* on its own will convey the intended meaning anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for noun

***Fanatic***

> A person filled with excessive and single-minded zeal, esp. for an extreme religious or political cause.

***Zealot***

> A person who is fanatical and uncompromising in pursuit of their religious, political, or other ideals.

If you're looking for *adjectives*

***rabid***

> Having or proceeding from a fanatical belief in something

***fanatical***

> Filled with excessive and single-minded zeal.

Comment: Good enough for me. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_(person)) says *Fanatic...introduced into English around 1550, means "marked by excessive enthusiasm and often intense uncritical devotion".* Though personally I'd say if OP doesn't like *blind worship* he might do better to just go with *uncritical devotion* anyway.

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 3):

When you love someone excessively and blindly you [idolise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idolise) them. This form of love and admiration is called **idolisation**.

Answer (score 3):

Adoration - The literal meaning is blind worship. As in "they adore money".

Answer (score 1):

**Idolatry**: Blind or excessive devotion to something.E.g:

> Their affection soon increased to almost idolatry.

**Blind**: Not willing to notice or unwilling to perceive or understand. Usually with "to" E.g:

> He is **blind to** his boyfriend/girlfriend's faults.

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a parasynthesis of the word using the prefix mis-.

> misworship

http://cleandictionary.com/#misworship

> To worship wrongly

Comment: blindly =/= wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

***infatuation***

[wordnetweb](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=infatuation): 'a foolish and usually extravagant passion or love or admiration.'

Answer (score 0):

My choice is going to be *dotage*: excessive fondness.